# Can I save a moldy mango seed that already sprouted?

Tags: plant-health, seeds, mold, sprouting, mango

I started growing this mango seed about aonth a half ago maybe two months. But I know I last watered it like maybe a month ago and it was watered well but a week later after I had I thought I drowned it and so I thought I threw it away. Turns out I put up somewhere I completely forgot about while looking for something I'm sure and now its been a month later and it's been growing. Its wrapped around a paper towel but it has black and green mold. Its definitely alive cause the stalk is green and hard. Doesn't look like it's dying at all. But the roots are black. Its been in a really humid place so it's been watering itself but the water is also mixed with mold. So it's been drinking moldy water. My question is can I save it? Or is it going to kill it if I transfer it. Like wash it off and put it in a fresh pot of dirt. Or is it just dead? Also would the fruit be even healthy at all if I can save it? Should I even save it?? Haha. Anyways any tips would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.

The black roots do indicate the plant is in trouble.  Whether there is enough live root hidden in there for the plant to recover, I couldn't say.  Eventually the plant needs to grow in soil.  Fail to transplant it, and eventually (perhaps soon) the plant for sure will die.  Transplant it and it might live.

The quantity and quality of the fruit is generally less on a stressed plant.  But with rare exceptions like green potatoes, stress does not make the edible parts of the plant any less safe to eat.  Also, a plant that gets a rough start in life like this one has might outgrow its troubles over a few years.  However, unless you will grow this mango outdoors in a frostless climate where it can become a full-size tree, there probably won't be any fruit.  https://www.bhg.com/gardening/vegetable/fruit/how-to-plant-a-mango-seed

Whether you *should* pot up your mango is a subjective matter that depends on how much you want the plant, etc.  We try to stick to questions of fact here rather than posting our opinions.  So I won't weigh in on what you should do.  But good luck.